# mgp25 instagram API - Fatal error: Class 'InstagramAPI\MediaAutoResizer' not found

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

someone knows about this error? Works normally before.
i use:

`$resizer = new \InstagramAPI\MediaAutoResizer($photoFilename);`

Comment: Show error: Fatal error: Class 'InstagramAPI\MediaAutoResizer' not found

Comment: Dd you include the files for the Instagram API?

Comment: Yes i include the require '../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: New API update dev master have bug.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade sdk and change class to work publish:

1) `composer require mgp25/instagram-php`

2) Change your `$var` in any new resize class:

`// Adjust the photo size
 $resizer = new \InstagramAPI\Media\Photo\InstagramPhoto($photo);`